# Synchronizing a passed ArrayList

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, arraylist

I have a project containing some JFrames and little points moving around and simulating creatures. These should be able to reproduce and die, therefore I need to modify the ArrayList with all living beings.

I read some things about synchronizing, though I did not really get the following:
I know that you can create either synchronized methods or variables when they are created. The ArrayList is created in a seperate JFrame and passed to the "**World**" class.

There is a class "**Actions**" which handles all actions such as die and reproduce, I also pass the ArrayList there to modify.

Also a class called "**Toolkit**" which handles generating things such as the starting population etc. The "**World**" contains a thread to repaint the creatures and make them move each tick.

Furthermore there is a class "**Paint**" which handles the graphic stuff and extending another JFrame for displaying Graphic.drawStrings, this class also gets the ArrayList to display the dead creatures.

So how and where do I have to create a synchronization to change the list while ticks are going on? 
The classes are quite big and messy, if you ask for code I will update my question with specified code in it.
Thanks for helping ^^

Simplified example:

Toolkit:

```
public static ArrayList<Creature> generateCreatures() {
    int amount_creatures = 10;
    ArrayList<Creature> all = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < amount_creatures; i++) {
            Creature creature = new Creature(id, sex, age, energy);
            all.add(creature);
        }
    }
    return all;
```

World:

```
public World(ArrayList<Creature> all ...) {
    this.all = all;
        ...
    startAnimation();
} 
private void startAnimation() {
        Toolkit.progress("Start Animation");
        startDrawThread();
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                Toolkit.step("Animation Thread started");
                try {
                    int warten;
                    long last = System.currentTimeMillis(), latest;
                    int ticks_ps = World.this.ticks_ps;
                    Toolkit.step("Ticks PS : " + ticks_ps);
                    float millsStepInterval = 1000f / ticks_ps;
                    int i = 1;

                    actions = new Actions(paint, World.this);

                    for (steps = 0; steps < Integer.MAX_VALUE - ticks_ps && running; steps++) {

                        nextTick();

                        latest = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        warten = Math.max(Math.round(millsStepInterval * i + (last - latest)), 0);

                        if (i == ACCURACY) {
                            i = 1;
                            last = latest + warten;
                        } else
                            i++;
                        Thread.sleep(warten);

                        synchronized (World.this) {
                            if (ticks_ps != World.this.ticks_ps) {
                                ticks_ps = World.this.ticks_ps;
                                millsStepInterval = 1000f / ticks_ps;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    interrupt();
                }
                Toolkit.step("Animation Thread finished");
            }
        }.start();

    }


private void nextTick() throws InterruptedException {

        for (Creature creature : all) {

            double moveratio = (double) (Math.random() * creature.getAge() / 100);


            if(moveratio < 5) {
                actions.move(all, creature, size.x, size.y);
            }
            else {
                actions.idle();
            }


            creature.setAge(creature.getAge() + 1);

            for(Creature creature1 : all) {
                for(Creature creature2 : all) {
                    if(Toolkit.isNextTo(creature1, creature2)){
                        if (creature1.getSex() != creature2.getSex()) {
                            if(creature1.getAge() > 1000 && creature2.getAge() > 1000) {
                                Creature mother = null;
                                if (creature1.getSex() == 1) {
                                    mother = creature1;
                                } else if (creature2.getSex() == 1) {
                                    mother = creature2;
                                }
                                actions.reproduce(mother, all);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }


        }
```

Actions:

```
public static void reproduce(Creature creature, ArrayList<Creature> all) {
        int id = Toolkit.getID(all);
        Creature baby = new Creature(id, energy, creature.getPosition(), 2, Toolkit.generateSex(), creature.getSize());
        all.add(baby);
    }
```

Paint:

```
public Paint(World world, ArrayList<Creature> all) {
        super();
        this.world = world;
        this.all = all;
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        deads = new boolean[all.size()]; //<-- THIS ONE HAS TO BE UPDATED EACH TIME THE LIST CHANGES
    }
```

Comment: Please, create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which describes your problem. It's far better than trying to describe it in words

Comment: You probably also want to read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/ if you haven't yet. It's possible you don't need to deal with explicit synchronization at all.

Comment: Since this is a Swing GUI, and you make no mention of work being done in a background thread, there is probably very little need to synchronize anything here, since likely all changes to the ArrayList will likely be made in a *single* thread, the Swing event thread or EDT (Event Dispatch Thread). This then begs the question: why do you think that you need synchronization here?

Comment: You could use a thread-safe Vector instead of an ArrayList - both implement the interface List. Or you could wrap the ArrayList in a class that enforces thread safety. Avoid trusting all recipients of the ArrayList to synchronize on it.

Comment: Without more details I can only suggest to check java.util.Vector. this implementation of java.util.List is synchronized by default, so only one thread at a time is able to modify it.

Comment: I just added some code, hope you can understand what I am aiming to do, I just created some code out of my mind so it is not safe to copy and paste. Also there are only some fragments out of a way larger code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use class `Colections`that provides method `public static <T> List<T> synchronizedList(List<T> list)` (See [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)) here). Also you can use class `Vector` which is a synchronized ArrayList but this is really old way. But before you do any of that read up on concurrency issues to understand if you really need to do this as synchronization is a very expansive luxury. Do you have different threads changing your list simultaneously? See if you really need it.

Comment: I guess by the following exception: Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException